# Meteor Mongo Insert Failed -- Access Denied

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, database

The first insert works fine, but the second Gives "Insert Failed: 403 -- Access denied" in the console. Auto subscribe is enabled, and I am on the auth branch. How do I set up my code so that I have a server MongoDB that clients can write to?

```
People = new Meteor.Collection('people'); 

if (Meteor.is_server) {
People.insert({name: 'Bob'});
}
if (Meteor.is_client) {
People.insert({name: 'Bob'});
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am on the auth branch.

Comment: Ok, so I'm guessing it is because I have no insert validator...

Comment: Exactly, you need to call `People.allow`.

Answer (score 21):

Because you are working with auth, you must allow or deny clients trying to do inserts, updates, removes, and fetches. To fix this specific issue you must add Collection.allow() to let the client's insert work.

```js
if(Meteor.is_server) {

  People.allow({
    'insert': function (userId,doc) {
      /* user and doc checks ,
      return true to allow insert */
      return true; 
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: As a side note for the inexperienced reader: the code snippet in this answer may not be safe for your case. 
This snippet allows _any_ client to update the related collection (i.e., People). 
If you are using Meteor's new Accounts API (http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api), you need to return a check on the logged user (e.g., return userId && doc.owner === userId, where owner is a fetched attribute of your collection).
See the Example section in http://docs.meteor.com/#allow

Comment: I had to put it outside the is_server namespace for this to work.

Answer (score 8):

Use method allow() in the Collection People. This method assign access CRUD.

```
function adminUser(userId) {
  var adminUser = Meteor.users.findOne({username:"admin"});
  return (userId && adminUser && userId === adminUser._id);
}
Lugares.allow({
  insert: function(userId, lugar){
    return adminUser(userId);
  },
  update: function(userId, lugares, fields, modifier){
    return adminUser(userId);
  },
  remove: function (userId, docs){
    return adminUser(userId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why 'Lugares'? Maybe it should be 'People'?

Comment: This answer is not really related to the question is it?

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?  It shows the three allow functions you need to add handlers for.  Also this code needs to run on the client AND the server, so this is more appropriate.  (Client side it pre-calculates the results of calling this and skips a server round trip.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this error after I removed **insecure** package from my project.

```
meteor remove insecure
```

Following fixed my problem.

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    // only allow posting if you are logged in
    return !! userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: setting up a Meteor.methods and then calling them on the client by Meteor.call('methodname', params), will fix this as well.

reference: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods

Answer (score 2):

If you have only testing project such as simple-todos tutorial, you can solve it with adding the insecure package

```
meteor add insecure
```